# How to make the title of the book bolder than \bf?

Tags: fonts, titles, titling

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
% Title
\usepackage{titling}
\author{}
\pretitle{\begin{center} \huge\bf} \title{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral3\relax} MY\\BOOK} \posttitle{\end{center}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

I need to make the title bolder than I am getting. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since LaTeX2e was introduced in 1993.

Comment: computer modern is only available in two weights.  It is also a very light font, you could change your entire book to eg a times roman clone (`\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`) which would be a darker font.

Comment: If you have a font that has extrabold or ultrabold etc, you could use that via `fontspec` package (example with Arial: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605192/how-to-select-arial-black-font-xelatex). Noto Serif font has many weights; so  do many other fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a larger font than a smaller bolder font. BTW use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`.

```
% booktitleprob.tex  SE 605001
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{comment}
% Title
\usepackage{titling}
\author{}
\begin{comment} % the original
\pretitle{\begin{center} \huge\bf} 
  \title{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral3\relax} MY\\BOOK} 
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\end{comment}
% the revision
\pretitle{\begin{center} \Huge\bfseries} 
  \title{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral3\relax} MY\\BOOK} 
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```