# How to select arial black font XeLatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm making a resume and want to use arial black. Here is my code:

`\name{{\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont {myName}}}`

What do I have to put instead of arial to get arial black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{arial.ttf}myName
\setmainfont{ariblk.ttf}myName
\end{document}
```

[image]

In pdflatex, using the `uarial` package, bold is supported, but I don't think the thicker black version is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
 myName \bfseries myName
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using XeLatex, it says: Package fontspec Error: The font "ariblk" cannot be found.

Comment: @maxbear123 Well, you can't use a font unless you have it.  With XeLaTeX, it uses system fonts from your computer.  For decades, the Arial fonts were part of the standard system release on Windows PC systems.  If you don't already have the Arial fonts on your computer, you would have to download them and install them.

Comment: @maxbear123 The other possibility is that Arial Black font file has a name that is different from `ariblack.ttf`.  You would have to examine your installed fonts to determine the exact name.

Comment: It was because I was using overleaf and thus did not have access to local files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using fontspec, and the recommendeded font series names in the latex font guidelines (`texdoc fntguide`), Arial Black can be assigned to `ub` (ultrabold) series, regular width:

[image: Arial weights and shapes]

There's a condensed version (called Narrow), which can go into the `*c` (for condensed) series/widths category, and there's also a rounded bold (which in the example I've put into the `eb` series/regular width category, as a closest match).

The corresponding commands (`\textub{}` etc) then are defined and available for use.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Path = c:/windows/fonts/, 
         Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont     = *,
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi,
    FontFace = {eb}{\shapedefault}{ARLRDBD},
    FontFace = {ub}{\shapedefault}{ariblk},
%
    FontFace = {c}{\shapedefault}{*N},
    FontFace = {c}{it}{*NI},
    FontFace = {bc}{\shapedefault}{*NB},
    FontFace = {bc}{it}{*NBI},
]{arial}
    
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cseries}{\fontseries{c}\selectfont}  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textc}{\cseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bcseries}{\fontseries{bc}\selectfont}    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbc}{\bcseries}

    
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubseries}{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textub}{\ubseries}



\newcommand\testtext{{\large myName}}%  \fontname\font}

\begin{document}


%------------------------------
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!12}
Font & Series & Upright & Italic \\
medium & 
m & 
\fontseries{m}\selectfont\testtext  &
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
%
bold & 
b & 
\fontseries{b}\selectfont\testtext  &
\fontseries{b}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
%
extrabold & 
eb & 
\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\testtext  &
-- \\
%\fontseries{eb}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
%
ultrabold & 
ub & 
\fontseries{ub}\selectfont\testtext  &
-- \\
%\fontseries{ub}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
\hline
{medium narrow\Large\phantom{L}}& 
c & 
\fontseries{c}\selectfont\testtext  &
\fontseries{c}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
%
bold narrow & 
bc & 
\fontseries{bc}\selectfont\testtext  &
\fontseries{bc}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\testtext  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
rounded bold = \texteb{abc} 

black = \textub{abc}

%===

\end{document}
```